# Azure not returning static assets - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, azure

I have been stuck with this issue for days now, with no clue or idea on how to solve this. It would be great if someone could help me out here.

I have a Angular application hosted on Azure Web app. Everything works fine. However, at times some or all of the JS files that were compiled (main.js, polyfills.js, runtime.js scripts.js or styles.css) doesn't load.

The code I used to build `ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none`

At that time the application returns the index.html which results in the following error displayed on the browser.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

The application expects a JS but, it is getting the index.html due to some reason. As a result the error points at the 1st character of the html file. `<`.

I have included part of my Package.Js and Angular.js files.

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
     ...
```

Angular.JSON

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "MyAPp": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:application": {
                    "strict": true
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
                            "lodash",
                            "@opentelemetry/api",
                            "stacktrace-js",
                            "error-stack-parser",
                            "stacktrace-gps",
                            "stack-generator"
                        ],
                        "outputPath": "../wwwroot",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/custom-theme.scss",
                            "src/controls.css",
                            "src/styles.css"



                        ],
                        "scripts": [


                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [{
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "2mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "3mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "MyApp:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "MyApp:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "MyApp:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [

                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json",
                            "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "MyApp"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "MyApp:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "MyAPP",
    "cli": {
        "analytics": "xxxx-xcx-4xxf-xxxx-4cxxxxxxx9b5"
    }
}
```

StartUp.cs

Further, the Startup.cs file looks like this,

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                    await next();
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                    await next();
              
                

            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();
        }
    }
```

When I get the error, the files I have mentioned are in memory cache. Please have a look at the attachment.

[image]

Note: If you require any information or code please let me know. At this point I need this bug sorted :)

SERVER ERROR:

**System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.**

This is been thrown at `context.Request.Path = "/index.html";` in the StartUp.cs file given above.

Comment: Are you editing against this deployment? ie. dev cycle: Edit -> push repo -> server builds and deploys?

Comment: No I am not. I am publishing via Visual Studio.

Comment: Also, please change the title to something like "Azure not always returning static assets".

Comment: So you are compiling in VS, and then only deploying (uploading) the built assets to Azure?

Comment: done. Azure actually.

Comment: Yes - Azure - sorry.

Comment: I am compiling with `ng build --aot --prod --output-hashing none` and then publishing via VS to Azure.

Comment: OK, it is very likely the caches are stale. I'm assuming you publish and immediately test?

Comment: I have been clearing cache as well. Today is day 3 working on this issue :)

Comment: A bit more detail in your question could have saved us both a bunch of time. Server configuration details will be helpful. Best of luck to you. Did I mention your question needs more details :-)

Comment: It works the fist time, and then when I reload the app after 5 minutes I get these errors.

Comment: What exactly do you require ? I am clueless to what I need to provide

Comment: I voted to close this question because you've provided no debugging info. **Server Logs <-- Start here** - look for errors or anomalies (like content type headers being incorrect or anything).

Comment: This: "_when I reload the app after 5 minutes I get these errors_" - the server instance the static assets resides on is going to sleep?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have included the server error . `System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.` Any clue please?

Comment: Looks like you've created a race condition in which the static files middleware collides with the existing context? This is a guess. You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57557663/9078341) helpful.

Comment: It was indeed helpful. I resolved it. Thank you so much. @RandyCasburn

Comment: Glad to you got it sorted. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Sharon Watinsan & @Randy Casburn for solving the issue , Converting it is an answer to help other community members for the similar issues  .

> System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the
> response has already started

For the above error as followed by this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545031/response-has-already-started-exception-in-a-bare-bones-asp-net-core-middleware/57557663#57557663) suggested by @McGuireV10 ,

> when my middleware is able to handle the request fully (either
> upgrading HTTP to WS, or sending back the echo client HTML) it should
> not hand off context to the next delegate. However, in this very
> simple example other requests (such as a browser trying to retrieve
> favicon) my middleware doesn't do anything, so the solution was this:
>
> ```
> finally
> {
>     if(!context.Response.HasStarted)
>         await next(context);
> }
> ```